# Data Cleaning in Python/Pandas to iterate through months combinations

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some data cleaning to do some machine learning on a data set.
Basically I would like to predict next 12 months values based on last 12 months.
I have a data set with values per month (example below).

I would like to train my model by iterating into each possible combination of 12 months.
For example I want to train him on 2014-01 to 2014-12 to populate 2015-01 to 2015-12 but also to train him on 2014-02 to 2015-01 to populate 2015-02 to 2016-01 etc.

But I struggle to populate all these possibilities.
I show below where I am currently in my code and an example below of what I would like to have (with just 6 months instead of 12).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]]
Months=['201401','201402','201403','201404','201405','201406','201407','201408','201409','201410','201411','201412','201501','201502','201503','201504','201505','201506','201507','201508','201509','201510','201511','201512']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=Months)
```

The part that I can't get to work.

```
X = np.array([])
Y = np.array([])

for month in Months:
    loc = df.columns.get_loc(month)
    print(month,loc)
    if loc + 11 <= df.shape[1]:
       X = np.append(X,df.iloc[:,loc:loc+5].values,axis=0)
       Y = np.append(Y,df.iloc[:,loc+6:loc+1].values,axis=0)
```

This is what I am expecting (for the first 3 iteratios)

```
### RESULTS EXPECTED #### 
X = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6,7,8]] 
Y =  [[7,8,9,10,11,12],[8,9,10,11,12,13],[9,10,11,12,13,14]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate date ranges like the ones you describe in your explanation (rather than the ones shown in your sample output), you could use Pandas functionality like so:

```
import pandas as pd

months = pd.Series([
'201401','201402','201403','201404','201405','201406',
'201407','201408','201409','201410','201411','201412',
'201501','201502','201503','201504','201505','201506',
'201507','201508','201509','201510','201511','201512'
])

# this function converts strings like "201401"
# to datetime objects, and then uses DateOffset
# and date_range to generate a sequence of months
def date_range(month):
    date = pd.to_datetime(month, format="%Y%m")
    return pd.date_range(date, date + pd.DateOffset(months=11), freq='MS')

# apply function to original Series
# and then apply pd.Series to expand resulting arrays
# into DataFrame columns
month_ranges = months.apply(date_range).apply(pd.Series)

# sample of output:
#            0          1          2          3          4          5   \
# 0  2014-01-01 2014-02-01 2014-03-01 2014-04-01 2014-05-01 2014-06-01   
# 1  2014-02-01 2014-03-01 2014-04-01 2014-05-01 2014-06-01 2014-07-01   
# 2  2014-03-01 2014-04-01 2014-05-01 2014-06-01 2014-07-01 2014-08-01   
# 3  2014-04-01 2014-05-01 2014-06-01 2014-07-01 2014-08-01 2014-09-01
```

Comment: Also, for the data you can just generate a range: list(range(1,25))